# zero padding problem

Tags: word-embeddings, embeddings

i need to implement this code by using padding

```
PAD=0
embeddings = []
for sent_idx in  sentences:
    # pad sentence to correct size
     while len(sent_idx) < 49:
           sent_idx.append(PAD)
```

but got

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

`sent_idx`  returns restaurant has modern wooden tables and chairs

`len(sent_idx)` returns 46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, each sentences `sent_idx` in `sentences` is a string. However, it should not be a string but a list of integers representing token indexes.

You must tokenize your sentence (i.e. split it into pieces and convert each piece of text in a numeric index to the token table) before appending any padding token.

Comment: you mean each sentence should like that  [2317, 4605, 3561, 2007, 5785, 3139, 1999, 11546, 1999, 20238, 12901]

Comment: i tried the above comment but got TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Each sentence should be like that, so in `sentences` you should have a list of those things: `sentences = [[2317, 4605, 3561, 2007, 5785, 3139, 1999, 11546, 1999, 20238, 12901]]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that sent_idx is a string not a list and append only work for list.
You can do the following :

```
list(sent_idx).append(PAD)
This will treat every character of sentence as a list element and append the padding
```